# Making sense of generic method complicated by inheritence and interface implementation

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I have a base class DataSource implementing and a generic interface IDataSource

```
class DataSource
{
DataSource (DateTime dt){}
DataSource (IData data) {}
DataSource (IData data, DateTime dt){}
}

public interface IDataSource<TValue> where TValue:IData
{
        TValue DataEntry{get;set;}
        string RootFolder { get; }
}
```

My derived classes (without any members)

```
 BestSource : DataSource, IDataSource<BestData> {}

 ConsistentSource :DataSource, IDataSource<ConsistentData> {}

 BackupSource :  DataSource, IDataSource<BackupData> {}
```

now I was trying to create an extension method on IData that would create the appropriate class and get the data from it...

```
public static IEnumerable<TValue> GetAllData<TValue, TSource>(this IData entity) 
        where TSource : DataSource, IDataSource<TValue>
        where TValue : IData
    {
        string folderName = $"_{entity.Name}";

        //One way I kinda got it work (well atleast not show compiletime errors)                                         
       //was to create a method in base class DataSource that used 
       //if-else cascade to return an appropriate instance...

       TSource dataSource =  (TSource) new DataSource(entity).GetSource(t);

       //but that's obviously a bad way of doing it. 
        //I want to avoid using reflection for no other reason than to just learn more about inheritence and working around/with it. 
        //I need an instance of it so I can access the json files at the rootfolder directory and also to deserilize the json.



        var returnData = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dataSource.RootFolder+folderName)
                       .Select(x => 
                          JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TValue>(File.ReadAllText(x)));
        return returnData;
    }
```

A simple solution that worked earlier was to just pass it an instance of DataSource's derived class. But then I tried to see how I could just get it to figure out the derived class from the type param of the Interface it implements. 
It's my first time trying to use generics.

Edit: Ok so I was able to get it to do what I wanted by creating a parameterless constructor in all DataSource subclasses. I really wanted to avoid this because it came at the expense of making my properties mutable by adding a setter. EArlier I was just setting them from inside the constructor and that worked well. I'll keep looking for some way to get back to that while still keeping the functionality of the extension method.

Comment: This looks like C#. You should apply the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Can you please post all the relevant code - including the members - and make sure it is compilable? Right now your code is hard to work with and therefore the question is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Not so generic version) You could try expressions:

```
public static IEnumerable<TValue> GetAllData<TValue>(this TValue entity, Func<DataSource<TValue>> func)
    where TValue : IData
{
    var obj = func();
    // Get some data from obj, will be of type BestSource in this example
    return new List<TValue>() { obj.DataEntry };
}
```

Somewhere in code:

```
BestData data = new BestData();
var receiver = data.GetAllData(() => new BestSource(data));
```

Also I did define DataSource as such:

```
public class DataSource<TValue> : IDataSource<TValue> where TValue : IData
```

And BestSource as:

```
public class BestSource : DataSource<BestData>
```

Also to write less code, you could define extension method GetAllData for every data type:

```
public static IEnumerable<BestData> GetAllData(this BestData entity)
{
    return entity.GetAllData(() => new BestSource(entity));
}
```

Somewhere in code:

```
var receiver2 = data.GetAllData();
```